# Embed GitHub Gist using Remix

Tags: reactjs, remix.run

Is it possible to embed a Gist in Remix? I'm trying to embed the following [gist](https://gist.github.com/AnthonyLzq/7d1cfeda389b7f5f38b62bd2640a32ba.js) in Remix using:

```html
<script src='https://gist.github.com/AnthonyLzq/7d1cfeda389b7f5f38b62bd2640a32ba.js'></script>
```

But it is not displaying anything.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that React is trying to hydrate the `<script>` element. Since you don't want React to process this, you need to treat it as raw HTML.

```js
<div
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
    __html: `<script src="https://gist.github.com/AnthonyLzq/7d1cfeda389b7f5f38b62bd2640a32ba.js"></script>`,
  }}
/>
```

[image: Embedded Gist]